# How create Java Desktop application autoupdate?

Tags: java, mysql, desktop-application

I have a few months programming in java and I are applying in my work a desktop application that is installed and that the opened check if this updated or not and if not upgrade a server on the Internet.

The program consists of PDF documents, but those documents are constatemente making changes.

The idea is that the update is downloaded to the person the most current documents.

How do I can do with java desktop?

Comment: That's a very broad question. First, you need to know what version the client has and version(s) are available on the server. You then need a way to download and replace those. A version control system (SVN, GIT) suddenly comes to mind, but might be a little  over the top of something like this.

Comment: but I use classes I read Java Web start, but how would the database?

Comment: Questions usually include either an attempt or *specific* problem you are having with understanding your goal. Your question currently sounds like a walkthrough request, which are frowned upon here. Please be more specific about what you don't understand

Answer (score 0):

Look on [Java Web Start](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Web_Start) technology. It's not exactly what you need but with ability to start your application from Internet it allows every time launch the latest application version.

Here is [example](http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-web-start-jnlp-tutorial-unofficial-guide/) how to create and deploy simple Java application.

Practical example of this technology is [muCommander](http://www.mucommander.com) file manager [Java Web Start launch](http://www.mucommander.com/webstart/mucommander.jnlp)